# Conditional independence situation with three variables

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, random-variable, independence, conditional-independence

Say we have three random variables, $X, Y$ and $Z$, where $X$ is independent of $Z$ (but not $Y$).

Does $E\bigg[ \dfrac{X}{f(Y,Z)} \bigg| Y \bigg] = E[X|Y] * E\bigg[ \dfrac{1}{f(Y,Z)} \bigg|Y \bigg]$?

Basically, conditioning on $Y$, is $X$ independent of $f(Y,Z)$, where $f$ is some function of $Y$ and $Z$?

I need this as a step in a proof and it looks simple, but I don't know how to show it definitively. Thank you!

Comment: Even though $X$ and $Z$ are (marginally) independent they may be conditionally independent conditional on $Y$.  If so, the above would be true.

Answer (score 0):

Counterexample:

- $X, Z$ are both Bernoulli distributed with parameter 0.5.
- $Y = 6$ if $X = Z = 1$ and $Y = 7$ otherwise.
- $f(Y, Z) = Z + 1$.

Conditioning on $Y = 7$, there are 3 equally likely possibilities for the values of $X$ and $Z$: `0,0; 0,1; 1,0`. You'll find that your equality doesn't hold.